# Moving Sections and Pages in OneNote for Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-onenote-2013

Microsoft released OneNote for Mac.  I used it this afternoon for goal setting and quickly ran into a challenge re-arranging sections and pages.  I want to be able to move a section or a page to another notebook... but can't figure it out.

I know it can be done on OneNote for Windows.

Thanks!

Comment: Somewhere along the way this feature was added.  I'm now on v15.xxxx and you can move pages between notebooks.

Answer (score 1):

To move page to another notebook in OneNote on Mac:

- Right-click on the page and select "Cut"
- Browse to the notebook you want to move to
- Right-click on the right-side pane (below the other pages) and select "Paste".

Yes, on OneNote for Windows it is much easier: right-clicking on the notebook brings up an option to move the page. Not sure if/when this easier option will be added to the mac.

On OneNote of iPad it is not possible to move a page (as of July 2014).

Update: as of late 2014 it is possible to move pages to other notebooks on iOS: 
- Click the "share" icon (box with arrow pointing up). It is located at top-right of screen.
- There are options to delete, move, email and sync the page. Select "Move Page".
- The final screen lists all your notebooks. Select the notebook you want to move your page to.

Answer (score -1):

While I don't know the program myself, I do know that many OS X apps support using the search bar in the help menu to find menu items. Search for what you want to do in that menu, and it will help you find the functionality you're looking for.

For example, if you wanted to save your document, but you don't know where the save function is, you could search for `save` in the help menu, and it would open the file menu and highlight the save entry.

Comment: If you don't know the program, why answer the question?

Comment: Because I'm familiar with the environment and know a baseline of what tools and elements can help, no matter the program.